# Multiple edit_data functions

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have multiple functions I used from previous projects, that I have included below. They all perform the same function. They update `contenteditable` fields in a PHP table. The table calls the JS function, runs the query the JS function calls for, and bam! Works great! However, it no longer works great since I have to utilize this in 2 different cases. I have one to update an "ETA" and one to update a "Sort" or "Category" (those are for the same table - so they use one query). Now that I have the sort/category function, it overrides the ETA function and tries to run the `edit_data` function for the sort/category when I'm updating an ETA, so it fails. My question boils down to this:
**How can I modify these queries so both of them work separately without moving them to separate files?**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
     function edit_data(id, text, column_name)  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"/eldis/master/usersc/includes/tasks/updateeta.php?uid="+num,  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},  
                dataType:"text",  
                success:function(data){  
                     alert(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }  
      $(document).on('blur', '.boeta', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id14");  
           var boeta = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, boeta, "boeta");  
      });  

      function edit_data(id, text, column_name)  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"/eldis/master/usersc/includes/tasks/updatesort.php?uid="+num,  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},  
                dataType:"text",  
                success:function(data){  
                     alert(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }  
      $(document).on('blur', '.sort', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id31");  
           var sort = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, sort, "sort");  
      });  
 });
```

Comment: See here, `url:"/.../updatesort.php?uid="+num,`From where you're getting `num` in the url?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul `num` is defined in an earlier function - that part works great.

Comment: You can do multiple listeners like: `$(document).on('blur', '.boeta,.sort', function(){...` then use an if/else with `hasClass()` and you can combine both instances into one. I think that is what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Rasclatt - I think you are totally on to what I need! Are you able to post an example for me? I'm still new to JS and doing my best but I cannot figure this one out.

Comment: You can do what is answered below as well, essentially the same thing I would propose, but I would probably make an ajax object wrapper so you don't have to keep retyping the `$.ajax()` over and over again. Inevitably you will likely want to use ajax outside of this one function. For right now, the answer below should work fine.

Comment: @Rasclatt - you are a life saver! A+ to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing two different `edit_data()` functions with same name, write only one function which uses different URL based on the `column_name`, like this:

```
function edit_data(id, text, column_name){  
    var url = "/eldis/master/usersc/includes/tasks/";
    if(column_name == "boeta"){
        url += "updateeta.php";
    }else if(column_name == "sort"){
        url += "updatesort.php";
    }
    url += "?uid=" + num;
    $.ajax({  
        url: url,  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},  
        dataType:"text",  
        success:function(data){  
             alert(data);  
        }  
    });  
}
```

Comment: @BrandinArsenault Happy to hear, glad I could help. :-)